# How to include function names for dll project in performance profiler for visual studio (2019)

Tags: visual-studio, performance, profiling, cpu-load

I am attempting to profile functions within a dll of my own creation that is called via the host project 'CPPConsoleTest'- effectively a test runner.

Following available guides, I have included folders that contain pdp files, this has allowed for some top level functions to be mapped from hex, but still no luck with the dll functions.

Note: I am open to other profile tools/suggestions if this is simply a limitation with vs19 tools.

Please see the following image

[image: Hex displayed instead of functions even with additional symbols loaded]